# Django: multiple update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to update multiple instances of my models. I can currently update them one by one just fine.

I want to be able to update them with a PUT request to my URL:

```
www.my-api.com/v1/mymodels/
```

with the request data like so:

```
[ { "mymodel_id": "id1", "name": "foo"}, { "mymodel_id": "id2", "alert_name": "bar"} ]
```

If I try it this way now, I receive the following Django error:

```
Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default, only multiple create.
For updates it is unclear how to deal with insertions and deletions.
If you need to support multiple update, use a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update()` so you can specify the behavior exactly.
```

My model has a Serializer class `MyModelSerializer`

```py
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializerWithFields):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        if instance.name is None:
            del data['name']
        return data
```

`ModelSerializerWithFields` extends `serializers.ModelSerializer`.
The View for MyModel is very basic:

```
class MyModelViewSet(MultipleDBModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
```

`MultipleDBModelViewSet` extends [`BulkModelViewSet`](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk), and contains

```py
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        ids = self.request.query_params.get("ids", None)
        if ids:
            return queryset.filter(pk__in=json.loads(ids))
        # returns normal query set if no param
        return queryset
```

At which level do I need to use the `ListSerializer` class? ie: in `ModelSerializerWithFields` or in `MyModelSerializer`? Or somewhere else completely?

If anyone has any examples of this implementation, I'd be very grateful

Comment: can you please post code of View related to this serializer?

Comment: @sam I added the view :)

Answer (score 1):

Serializer Must be inherited from BulkSerializerMixin

So the serializer code will be like

```
from rest_framework_bulk.serializers import BulkListSerializer, BulkSerializerMixin

class SimpleSerializer(BulkSerializerMixin,
                       ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = SimpleModel
        # only required in DRF3
        list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
```

At Viewset don't forget to use the
    `filter_queryset` method. 
    So your view will be like

```
class MyModelViewSet(MultipleDBModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.none()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(<some_filtering>)
```

Comment: Ah yes, there us a `filter_queryset` method in the class it inherits from!

Comment: I updated the post to include that, but what is this: ``look_url_kwarg = '<kwarg_name>'?

Comment: You can leave this. If you are have not changed lookup field. It's basically the field name by which the queryset get filtered. You can ignore this at this point.

Comment: So ... What changes can I make to carry out bulk updates?

Comment: From where you are getting ModelSerializerWithFields?

Comment: "ModelSerializerWithFields extends serializers.ModelSerializer"